# Alterar output de clase filha em um contador de tempo

Tags: java, android-studio, timer, clock

Bom dia, estou tentando criar um placar de basquete para começar a aprender a programação em java/android studio.

Criei uma classe para o cronometro do tempo de jogo chamado temporizador que está funcionando muito bem. Agora quero extender essa classe para criar o shootclock (é o relógio que conta a posse de bola, ele roda junto com o placar, mas tem apenas 24 segundos.)

Como toda a implementação é igual, decidi extender para a classe ShootClock() e apenas fazer um override no método de visualização e no construtor para que ele tenha apenas 24 segundos. Porém, estou tentando criar um override para o método  atualizarContagem(){}, que exibe o tempo no placar, mas não consigo puxar as variaveis da classe mãe.

Esse é o metodo da classe mãe.

```
public void atualizarContagem() {
          int minutes = (int) (tempoAteAcabar / 1000) / 60;
          int seconds = (int) (tempoAteAcabar / 1000) % 60;

         tempoAteAcabarFormatado = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
         tempoPartida.setText(tempoAteAcabarFormatado);
    }
```

A principio achei que conseguiria resolver mudando apenas o código. Mas obviamente não entendi como funciona a sintaxe nesse momento

```
public void atualizarContagem() {
          int seconds = (int) (super.tempoAteAcabar / 1000) % 60;

         tempoAteAcabarFormatado = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"%02d:%02d", seconds);
         tempoPartida.setText(tempoAteAcabarFormatado);
    }
```

Comment: Não entendi bem seu problema, mas a princípio, a classe Temporizador deve (ou deveria) ter um método, sei lá, `countdown(int seconds)`, em que você passaria a quantidade de segundos. Aí basta passar o equivalente em segundos para a duração da partida (ou do quarto) e, numa outra chamada, os 24 segundos da posse de bola. Tudo isso pra dizer que você não precisa criar objetos e lógicas distintas para lidar com, aparentemente, dois problemas iguais.

Comment: Concordo plenamente com o @StatelessDev. Vc não precisa ter um contador pra cada coisa, um contador genérico já resolve tudo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok se entendi bem, seu problema é que não consegue acessar as variaveis `tempoAteAcabarFormatado`, e `tempoPartida` correto ?
Se a resposta for sim, na sua classe principal(herdada), essas variaves provavelmente devem esta assim:

```
private String tempoAteAcabarFormatado;
private VARIAVEL tempoPartida;
```

Para conseguir acessa-las você deve ter os métodos getters e setter. Sua IDE deve ta mostrando elas para você porem não esta deixando você opera-las porque não deve ter os getters/setters.

Você também pode usar o LOMBOK para que ele gere isso, porem se esta aprendendo não recomendo usar framework ou plugins.

Assim seus métodos ficariam assim...

```
public void atualizarContagem() {
      int seconds = (int) (super.tempoAteAcabar / 1000) % 60;

     setTempoAteAcabarFormatado(String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"%02d:%02d", seconds));
     getTempoPartida().setText(getTempoAteAcabarFormatado());
}
```